# Wireless display with Raspberry PI 3

Tags: pi-3, pi-3b+, wireless

So, I Googled around for this, but it feels like almost all questions on the internet about this kind of thing are "how to stream from my laptop to my pi".

I was wondering about the other way around. I have a TV that I can cast wirelessly to, from my laptop. It's an LG tv with magic remote, and when casting wirelessly, I can even use the magic remote to click things on the screen, and that is pretty useful.

Is it possible to do the same thing with Raspberry Pi? Wirelessly connect it to TV (Miracast?)? Ideally, magic remote would work all the same as it works on my windows laptop.

If it is not possible, what is the issue (if Wi-Fi driver - maybe USB dongle can help)?

If anyone has link to some documentation, or a website or a project, I can take it from there. If anyone has a complete solution, even better :)

Comment: Search for "miracast linux" and you will find a few things, at a glance this looked the most viable: https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast

Comment: The Display-Source side allows you to connect external displays to your system and stream local content to the device. A lot of effort is put into making this as easy as connecting external displays via HDMI. Note: This is not implemented yet. Please see #4.